# Looking for a DB Schema Drawing tool on Mac OS X

Tags: database, drawing

I am looking for an easy-to-use database schema drawing tool for Mac.

No reverse-engineering nor database schema generation needed, just a simple drawing tool with pre-designed DB-related graphical components (boxes, relations-arrows, PK/FK symbols...).

Do you know any (non-commercial) good tool?

Answer (score 7):

Argo UML http://argouml.tigris.org/ is pretty good and although it's really aimed at producing UML diagrams it can also make reasonable looking schema pictures.

If you'd consider a commercial product, I use OmniGraffle [Omni Group](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle/) which is excellent.

Comment: Omnigraffle is excellent, and improving constantly